# How to politely ask why I wasn't told about Exit Interviews

Tags: management, human-resources, company-policy, business

I  have under 25% ownership in a small company that is about 12 months from being closed permanently.  My business partner hired a new HR person in December.  I recently found out that she is doing exit interviews but she never told me about it.  My business partner never told me, but that is normal, we rarely talk.  I think as an owner I should have been notified.  I would like to email HR and my business partner and ask why I wasn't notified. Any advise on how to write an email that would address the lack of communication regarding this new practice of exit interviews.

Comment: Having exit interviews is a standard HR practice. Are you normally notified when people do their jobs in a standard way? Were you notified before, that exit interview do not happen? Was it some kind of board decision that exit interviews are not to happen?

Comment: "Why wasn't I informed of the exit interviews?" - That seems like a pretty direct way of asking to me.

Comment: Is it customary at this company for every employee to notify you of all of the day to day tasks that they perform for their role?

Comment: I agree it is a standard practice.  We should have been doing it for years but it wasn't till recent that we had the HR person in place to handle it.

Comment: What adverse impact do you perceive due to not being notified?

Comment: "I think as an owner, I should have been notified." - You should talk to your business partner about the reasons, they did not tell this person, to notify you about the existence of these exit interviews.  However, what would be gained, by being told about these exit interviews at this point?   Your business is dissolving.

Comment: Why did you think that she wouldn't do exit interviews? Is she the newest person in an existing HR Department where no one else does these interviews or is she the first HR professional the company has had and she took over these duties from a person or persons who don't have education/training in HR?

Answer (score 2):

> I recently found out that she is doing exit interviews but she never told me about it.

It's not unusual for people to go about doing their jobs without telling even part owners of the company about every little detail.

> I think as an owner I should have been notified. I would like to email HR and my business partner and ask why I wasn't notified. Any advise on how to write an email that would address the lack of communication regarding this new practice of exit interviews.

Write the e-mail by hand, really pour all your thoughts and feelings on this matter into the text. **Then burn it** and go do something useful instead. Seriously, there's nothing to be gained by having a temper tantrum over something so trivial - they're doing their job, and so what if you'd have preferred to know about it sooner? You know now and they can't go back in time and retroactively let you know. Let it go.

As you mentioned in a comment:

> I agree it is a standard practice. We should have been doing it for years but it wasn't till recent that we had the HR person in place to handle it.

It's not a big deal - this HR person is doing their job, and from the sounds of it you *agree* with how their doing their job. They haven't gone rogue, they aren't doing something seriously out of the norms that you'd normally consider seeking approval for. So just let them get on with it and maybe start worrying about what you're going to do 13 months from now when the company has closed.